# All packages in a java project

Tags: java, class, project

I am looking to print out all classes in all of the packages in my Java project. For example, say the project contained

```
Package1.Class1
Package1.Class2
Package1.Class3
Package2.Class1
Package2.Class2
```

I would want to print out all of these packages and classes. Using the following code, I am able to list them, but only when I reference in the manner of `Package.Class c = new Package.Class();`

Here is the code I am trying to use:

```
Package[] pa = Package.getPackages();
for (int i = 0; i < pa.length; i++) {
    Package p = pa[i];
    System.out.print("\"" + p.getName() + "\", ");
}
```

Any thoughts on how I can do this?

Thanks all

Comment: *When* do you need it? At runtime or before packaging (let's say at compile time)?

Comment: duplicated? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/520328/can-you-find-all-classes-in-a-package-using-reflection

Answer (score 3):

There's no easy way due to the dynamic nature of classloaders.

However you could look at the reflections library : http://code.google.com/p/reflections/

Which will allow you to lookup the classes in the current classpath.

With that library you can try something like this:

```
 Reflections reflects = new Reflections("my.project.prefix");

 Set<Class<? extends Object>> allClasses = 
 reflects.getSubTypesOf(Object.class);
```

Answer (score 2):

Go with `reflections`, or parse the classpath, splitting it into individual folders and / or jar files, walking each of them and listing the packages. But that's way more complicated than using the reflections library.

Comment: @Kent I'd use the reflections library myself, but I just wanted to make clear that there are alternatives. Spring's classpath scanning technologies also come to mind.